# How to avoid repeatedly connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP script which is called every second from each user in my website:

```
<?php
$user = addslashes($_POST["user"]);
require("db.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id = $row["id"];
$date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() );

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE id_key = '$id'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
{ 
    $upload = mysql_query("UPDATE activity SET last_activity = '$date' WHERE id_key = '$id'");
    if (!mysql_query($upload))
    {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO activity (id_key, last_activity) VALUES ('$id', '$date')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to do it better or how to remove db connection every time, because this overloads my hosting cpu.

Comment: Do you really need to call it *every* second?

Comment: I will make chat and it is important to know if the user is online on the second.

Comment: Establishing a connection is probably the least of your worries, that's done in a few short microseconds. Building a chat server based on separate HTTP requests with PHP is probably the bigger issue here.

Comment: You could slow this to like 10-30 sec instead of 1 sec. For chats, use sockets and another technology (nodejs, continious workers).

Comment: You should really use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of the 3 or 4 calls you're using now. And you can JOIN to get the user's ID from the users table, rather than query the database first.

Comment: @deceze I know there is something wrong in my approach, but what are the right methods to build chat server?

Comment: [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) comes to mind

Comment: Think what you really need. Probably when you start a chat you need user data, but not every call. Why select whole user activity?

Comment: Why not tackle it the other way around and have an AJaX call running within `setTimout()`  to effectively "ping" a PHP script with a unique user/session hash? Only validate the users on the database when performing an action - otherwise just rely on that "ping" from the user's browser. If they close the browser, that JS script will no longer be pinging and you'll know they've gone away.

Comment: Also your query are exposing a treatful SQL injection there. Also, you're not using a framework, which exposes a layer of security and database handling.

Comment: @CD001 I'm making it that way. :)
And thanks to all I will take a look to node.js !

Comment: I'd recommend ejabberd, an XMPP chat server written in Erlang. Much better suited for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *PHP* you can't avoid that. *Apache* handles every request by starting a new, independent *PHP* process and thus a new connection to the database is required for every new process.

Indeed, the time necessary to establish a connection is small, but certainly it is not "a few short microseconds". Depends on your infrastructure it would take a few milliseconds to establish a connection.
Note that the drivers always establish a *TCP* socket, probably encrypted so there is some penalty in connecting, but in standard *PHP* environment it cannot be avoided.